# Tie comment to current page

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am currently working on an assignment from my university. The task is to construct a comment system using asp.net mvc. So I built a image gallery and everything is working smoothly, except commenting.

My problem is that comments are tied to specific pictures, but I am unsure how to pass the user and picture object from the view back to the controller.

PictureModel.cs

```
public class Picture
{
    [Required]
    public virtual int PictureId { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

CommentModel.cs

```
public class Picture
{
    [Required]
    public virtual int CommentId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual int UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual string Body { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMMM yyyy - HH:MM}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public virtual DateTime PostTime { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual Picture Picture { get; set; }
}
```

PictureDetailsViewModel.cs

```
public class PictureDetailsViewModel
{
    public User currentUser { get; set; }
    public Picture picture { get; set; }
    public string comment { get; set; }
}
```

PictureController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Comment(PictureDetailsViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if(model.comment != null) {
            var comment = new Comment { User = model.currentUser, Picture = model.picture, Body = model.comment, PostTime = DateTime.Now };
            db.Comments.Add(comment);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = model.picture.pictureID });
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

picture/details.cshtml

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Comment", "Picture", null, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.comment, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Write a comment..." })
    <input type="submit" class="form-control input-button" value="Submit" />
}
```

When I submit the form my controller maps to the correct action, but my model is missing values for picture and user like so:

```
model.currentUser = null;
model.picture = null;
model.comment = "test";
```

How would I proceed to extract the user and picture from the model?

Comment: You have not generated any controls for `User` or `Picture`. One option is to add hidden inputs for the `User.UserID` and `Picture.PictureId` properties (although probably not necessary for User, since you should already know this in the controller)

Comment: I tried this approach a bit earlier, but had some database context issues. I tried it again now and got those context issues sorted out and it works like a charm! However, is this the correct way to do it from a MVC perspective?  Post your comment as answer and I will accept.

Comment: Your `PictureDetailsViewModel` should only have properties that you display/edit in the view, so `Picture` and `User` should be replaced with properties of those models that are relevant. The controller is then responsible for mapping between you data and view model. Also you `Picture` model contains `ICollection<Comment>` but you view is only allowing a user to add one comment so not sure I understand you design.

Comment: I'm displaying all posted comments with `foreach (var item in Model.picture.Comments)` , if there is another way to do it which is more in the spirit of MVC I would be happy to learn.

Comment: For displaying comments, that's fine (I was talking about editing comments - your model suggest a user can have multiple comments for one picture but the form only allows a user to add one comment at a time) but your on the right track.